# Javascript how to make an form based on another form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make an form that is based on the myform checked checkboxes.

The myform2 should have all the checked checkboxes of myform2 with the same input fields.

How should I do this?

```
<h1>Heading 1</h1>
<form name="myform" method="POST" action="/cgi-bin/script.cgi">
<input name="box1" type="checkbox" value="Bike" />
<input name="box2" type="checkbox" value="Car" />
</form> 
<h2>Heading 2</h2>
<form name="myform2" method="POST" action="/cgi-bin/script.cgi">
<script type="text/javascript">
var i=5;
var b=0;
while (b<=i) {
    document.write('<br />' + '<input type="checkbox"' + 'value="Bike"' + '/>' + '<label for="male">'+ "Male" + '</label>' )
}
</script>
</form>
```

Comment: With jQuery that'd be a 2-liner, with pure javascript, you'd have to write more and in the end worry about cross-browser compatibility too.

Comment: Can you show me how it is done with jQuery?

Comment: so you want myForm2 to have all the fields of myForm and their values set?

Comment: I want to have that myForm2 should have all the checked checkboxes fields of myForm and their values

Comment: @Majid it may be easier in JQuery but I do not believe there are any notable browser compatibility traps around building DOM content for forms.

Comment: @Jim How about detecting a checkbox is checked? Would `document.forms[0].elements[n].getAttribute(“checked”)` work for all browsers? I'm asking really ;).

Comment: @tzown Should the second form be populated after an event occurs - e.g. a button is clicked? Because if it is to happen at page load you'd have no opportunity to check varying sets of checkboxes and form2'will always be the same; which doesn't make much sense.

Comment: It should not be after an event. Just instant

Comment: Did you know that JavaScript has a `for` loop? `for(var b = 0; b <= 5; b++)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something along these lines with jquery:

```
$('form:eq(0) input').clone().appendTo('form:eq(1)');
```

It should clone all the `input` dom elements under the first form element on the page and put them into the second form element on the page. Haven't tested this, but hopefully will do what you're looking for.

If you only wanted to copy the checked input elements, you can try something like this:

```
$('form:eq(0) input:checked').clone().appendTo('form:eq(1)');
```

However if you have checked radio buttons it will clone those too, if you want to prevent that you have to get fancier still, which will be something along the lines of:

```
$('form:eq(0) input:checkbox').filter(':checked').clone().appendTo('form:eq(1)');
```

This should copy across only the input elements that are of type checkbox and that are checked.

Comment: Does it clone only them there are checked?

Comment: The above will simply select all the input elements under the first form. If you want only the checked checkboxes you have to get a little fancier with the selectors, I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The way to go (in my view) is what you see in [skorks' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5713077/javascript-how-to-make-an-form-based-on-anaother-form/5714028#5714028). But if you have no choice other than doing it without a library, here is the js to do it.

```
<h1>Heading 1</h1>
<form name="myform" method="POST" action="/cgi-bin/script.cgi">
<input name="box1" type="checkbox" value="Bike" checked />
<input name="box2" type="checkbox" value="Car" />
</form> 

<h2>Heading 2</h2>
<form name="myform2" method="POST" action="/cgi-bin/script.cgi">

<script type="text/javascript">

var my_form = document.forms[0];
var num_inp = my_form.elements.length;
var me, i;
for (i=0; i<num_inp; i++) {
    me = my_form.elements[i];
    if(me.type === "checkbox" && me.checked)
    document.write('<input type="checkbox" value="' + me.value + '" name="' + me.name + '" checked /> ' + me.value + '<br/>');
}

</script>
</form>
```

By the way, it is not clear where you get the data for the `labels` of the generated `checkboxes`, the best choice was the `value` of the `checkbox` and I used that.